# SQL select sum with multiple where from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two tables in my MySQL, users and purchases.

User table contains Id, Name, Surname and so on. Purchase table contains Id, User_id, Status and Sum payed for something.

What I need is to get select from these two tables where I would have the sum of every item each user has buyed.

I've tried this with table 'users':

```
LEFT JOIN 'purchases'
ON 'users'.'id' = 'purchases'.'user_id'
SELECT SUM (sum) FROM 'users', 'purchases' WHERE 'purchases'.'status' = 'completed' AND 'purchases'.'user_id' = 'users'.'id'
```

But with this I get the same sum for each user, which is wrong. What should I write instead?

Would highly appreciate any possible help!

To provide some actual example, lets take this one:

```
Users:
Id: 1 Name: John
Id: 2 Name: Ann
Purchases:
Id: 10 Status: completed User_id: 1 Sum: 4.00
Id: 20 Status: completed User_id: 1 Sum: 8.00
Id: 30 Status: completed User_id: 2 Sum: 50.00
Id: 40 Status: completed User_id: 2 Sum: 100.00
```

After running the query I should get this:

```
 Id: 1 Sum: 12.00 
 Id: 2 Sum: 150.00
```

The query was made via Laravel, so I had just

```
DB::table('users')->leftJoin... ->select(DB::raw...
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. Also show us the whole attempted query.

Comment: To get `Id: 1 Sum: 12.00 
 Id: 2 Sum: 150.00` you needn't join `users` at all. You have user_id in `purchases`.

Comment: An inverted comma (') denotes a string. Use backticks (`) to denote table/column idenitifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Original Answer

First off, your submitted SQL was a mess, things were completely out of the conventional order, I'm not sure it would execute as presented. That said, this should do what you want, assuming I understand your desired output correctly:

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.surname, ROUND(SUM(purchases.sum),2) AS totalSum
FROM purchases
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = purchases.user_id
WHERE status='completed'
GROUP BY users.name, users.surname
ORDER BY users.id
```

The key aspect you were missing from your query was the `GROUP BY` section, I added `ORDER BY` for my own benefit on my fiddle, use it if you wish, or not.

Here's a fiddle I prepped for you prior to your posting of your sample data, the main answer has been given by others I see so I'm just posting this because I already did the work on it. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8fa2d/6/0

## Answer 2.0

Fiddle is acting up so this is untested but give it a try.

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.surname, ROUND(SUM(CASE WHEN purchases.status = 'completed' THEN purchases.sum ELSE 0 END),2) AS totalSum 
FROM users 
    LEFT JOIN purchases ON users.id = purchases.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY users.id
```

Comment: @AntDC also mentioned a useful tip which is providing an alias for the tables so you're not having to type out purchases and users all the time.

Comment: this query returns only those users who have some completed purchases, but I need to get all of them, with 0.00 or null or whatever if they have no completed purchases

Comment: Invalid GROUP BY, will not run on newer MySQL versions. (The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.)

Comment: @jarlh instead of editing other people's posts to comply with your formatting preference why don't you supply an answer since you've decided mine is no good.

Comment: Why I edited? Well, I found your answer hard to read, but still worth reading. When finished editing I noted that the GROUP BY wasn't up to date. I didn't downvote, I just added comment to inform you, OP and everyone else that this query wont run on newer MySQL versions.

Comment: And if you don't like my editing, you can rollback it!

Comment: @jarlh let's just bury the hatchet, I was just annoyed because it's 4:30 AM, I'm trying to help the guy, and you come along and edit, then say the solution I provided has an issue, without providing an alternative that fixes the issue. I was somewhat out of line and if you're not inclined to provide an answer that's fine.


YawningMilk -  I haven't given up on you, SQL Fiddle is acting up though

Comment: @YawningMilk it's pushing 5 AM here and SQL Fiddle isn't working right now. I can't test it to be 100% but I'm pretty sure this should do the trick (I'd prefer to test but fiddle is dead)

Edit: editing my answer with the alteration because the inline code thing is clashing with SQL formatting.

Comment: @YawningMilk updated my answer with a working solution, fiddle: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c18bd8/10 The reason for swapping `users` and `purchases` is that a `LEFT JOIN` retains all values from the `LEFT` table, i.e. the first one. By putting it first and using a `CASE` inside the `SUM` to test for completion it allows rows with no completed payments to display.

Comment: My pleasure, glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the field you want the aggretates to be based on.
I don't know your table structures but something like this should do.

```
SELECT 
  U.UserId, U.UserName, Sum(P.AmountPaid)
FROM Users U
LEFT OUTER JOIN Purchases P ON P.UserId = U.UserId AND P.Status = 'completed'
GROUP BY
 U.UserId, U.UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
  U.UserId, Sum(P.AmountPaid)
FROM Users U
LEFT OUTER JOIN Purchases P ON P.UserId = U.UserId 
GROUP BY
 U.UserId
```